# python 3.x shutil.copy FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.4, shutil

system  Windows 8.1 Python 3.4
Repeatedly get FileNotFound Errno2 , attempting to copy all files in a directory.

```
import os
import shutil
source = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Chess\\events\\")
for file in source :
    shutil.copy(file, "E:\\events\\")
```

yields

```
FileNotFoundError : [Errno2] No such file or directory 'aerofl03.pgn'.
```

Although `'aerofl03.pgn'` is first in the source list `['aerofl03.pgn', ...]`.
Same result if a line is added:

```
for file in source :
    if file.endswith('.pgn') :
        shutil.copy(file, "E:\\events\\")
```

Same result if coded

```
for file in "C:\\Users\\Chess\\events\\" :
```

My shutil.copy(sourcefile,destinationfile) works fine copying individual files.

Comment: Check the value for file and ensure it includes the full path

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir()` lists *only* the filename without a path. Without a full path, `shutil.copy()` treats the file as relative to your current working directory, and there is no `aerofl03.pgn` file in your current working directory.

Prepend the path again to get the full pathname:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\Chess\\events\\"
source = os.listdir(path)

for filename in source:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    shutil.copy(fullpath, "E:\\events\\")
```

So now `shutil.copy()` is told to copy `C:\Users\Chess\events\aerofl03.pgn`, instead of `<CWD>\aerofl03.pgn`.