# Python Shutil move failing: File Not Found

Tags: python, shutil

I get an error on the below code that says, `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Harry White.txt' -> 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove\\Harry White\\Harry White.txt'`

Can anyone help me?

```
import shutil
import os, sys

source = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove'
dest1 = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove\\Harry White'
dest2 = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove\\John Smith'
dest3 = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove\\Judy Jones'

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if f == "Harry White.txt":
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
    elif f == "John Smith.txt":
        shutil.move(f, dest2)
    elif f == "Judy Jones.txt":
        shutil.move(f, dest3)
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333467/python-3-x-shutil-copy-filenotfounderror

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python 3.x shutil.copy FileNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333467/python-3-x-shutil-copy-filenotfounderror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly understanding the `shutil.move` function.

**The `shutil.move(src, dst)`**

> Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst)
>   and return the destination.

**The `src` and `dst` must be the `full path` of the file or directory.**

You have to change your code, Try this:

```
import shutil
import os, sys

source = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove'
dest1 = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove\\Harry White'
dest2 = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove\\John Smith'
dest3 = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\z_testingmove\\Judy Jones'

files = os.listdir(source)
for filename in files:
    sourcepath = os.path.join(source, filename)
    if filename == "Harry White.txt":
        destpath = os.path.join(dest1, filename)
        shutil.move(sourcepath, destpath)
    elif filename == "John Smith.txt":
        destpath = os.path.join(dest2, filename)
        shutil.move(sourcepath, destpath)
    elif filename == "Judy Jones.txt":
        destpath = os.path.join(dest3, filename)
        shutil.move(sourcepath, destpath)
```